What else to check after rodent damage?
I had a rodent go through the engine, chew off some cables. No electricity on the vehicle at all. I spliced all the broken wires I could find and tried with a portable battery. Still no electricity at all. Checked the fuses as well. The vehicle is volvo xc70 2004 (essentially same with v70). I can't think of what else to check. I didn't check the fuses on the passenger compartment or in the trunk. Also, my wire strippers were quite bad. I might have damaged the adapter by excessively pulling on the cables while trying to strip them. Also, there weren't much length to make a solid connection.
Any other ideas? Mine sound like long shots to me.





My splices before taping up.

The length of cable before splicing.


Wow, that really sucks! They really did a number on your electrics. My suggestion? Fix what you can see is wrong, then fix stuff as you find stuff which doesn't work.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 unfortunately I fixed anything I could see. Still no electricity at all on the dash. What is next? Take a testing pen and go touch random wires? Not really an electrics person. The last 2 pictures are my attempt in fixing the thing if it wasn't clear.

What does "no electricity" mean? An old school term, 'idiot lights' from analog incandescent lamps are useful indicators. Digital leds do exactly the same thing when analog systems (carburetors and distributors) gave way to EFI systems when familiar with how old school turned to electronics. Idiot lights from the instrument panel give clues whether they turn on or not.

@FDryer I put in the key and turn. Nothing comes up on the dashboard. Not even the cabin lights (with a jumper attached too!)

With clarification, one main problem lies in power to the ignition switch. Wiring diagrams would be extremely helpful if you can search for free online info. One of the main fuses, labeled as 'IGNITION' or something similar, provides power to the ign switch. You may have to probe fuses for power and look underneath the fuse panel wiring for damage. This can be a long project. Insulation is made from vegetable matter and attract animals as a food source.

@FDryer with probing, do you mean sticking in a control pen and see if there is anything? I have wiring diagrams as well.

Yes, probing for 12v; test light, multimeter, whatever makes you comfortable, including using a T pin to pierce insulation to measure for 12v. Wiring diagrams; I suggest probing at either the fuse panel supplying power to the ignition switch or from the ignition switch. I'd start at basic power distributed to the ignition switch as power is sent to the ecm and beyond. And be sure of main grounds; between battery and chassis and chassis to engine block.
